# Add ability to paste images into editor directly

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Well, you know most of the users, frequently use Screenshots (**PrintScreen**) button. However, everytime I want to put image in SO answer/question, we have to:

- open PAINT > paste image >  save; Then in SO editor : drag action..

  [or]
- go to i.e. [OnPaste.com](http://OnPaste.com), paste image> upload> copy link and paste in SO editor.

I suggest to add the simplest feature:  Paste the image directly (Like OnPaste.com does).  It will be good these two options:  **Crop** and **simplest brush** to mark some places on image.

That will be a big time-saver for everyone... And you know, how much valuable is time for us.  (please, don't say: "use 3rd party tools!" or etc.)

Comment: I don't think the amount of effort needed to do this will be worth it. What percentage of SO questions need screenshots?

Comment: You *can* paste images directly. Click the 'image' button, paste. Or drag the image file to the dialog box. There is *no need to upload to another site first*.

Comment: @BSMP take a look in **Android** tagged questions (or any desktop-app related questions) and you will see that many need. p.s. Have I not said the **answers** (not only questions?)

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Printscreen?  Eew.  How about using the snipping tool (or similar) and capture only the relevant bits of the screen? It can optionally copy to the clipboard automatically, so you can then go do what Martijn says.

Comment: I think this is a good feature request. Recently there has been talk about SO not being nice to new comers. This is even one level superior in badway, downvoting a valid question badly! 

Meta has been the worst experience .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is **already implemented**. Just use the image button on the toolbar:

[image: editor toolbar with image tool circled]

then simply use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> on Mac) to paste the image in the clipboard to have it uploaded.

Alternatively, drag the image to that dialog box, or click on the drop target to open a file picker.

If you are frequently creating screenshots learn the tools of your platform, a modern OS lets you capture a region as well as the full screen, and then edit the result to add embellishments.

Then there are legion simple image editors that let you capture a region or screen and then crop and edit (I personally use [Skitch](https://evernote.com/skitch/) on Mac).

Comment: BTW, Martin,  please, tell me frankly, what steps did you do to paste this image here?  :)))))))))))   thanks, I didnt know that Paste was available from Buffer... However, **Crop** feature and a simple brush (or circles or arrows to be put on image) will be excellent!

Comment: @T.Todua: I doubt that that is going to happen anytime soon. I use Skitch for screenshots like the one I made here. Such tools are a dime a dozen (or free, as Skitch is).

Comment: https://evernote.com/skitch/, then command-shift-5, select region, click 'capture', draw a circle, command-C to copy, then paste into the dialog box.

Comment: ok, I am accpeting the answer as chosen. p.s. it's good if you include your above comment (about "that is going to happen anytime soon..") in answer.

Comment: p.s. 2.  I cant enter `evernote.com/skitch`, it says it's discontinued :) ...  hm,we obviously need that feature on SO ::

Comment: @T.Todua: Skitch is a Mac tool, there used to be a Windows version which was discontinued. See [Can one take a partial screen shot in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/404192) for Windows alternatives.

Comment: I appreciate your approach, however, in the initial question, I have even bolded and crossed the suggestion about using 3rd party tools. However, thanks, yes, I have installed many 3rd party tools.

Comment: @T.Todua: Did you properly read the Windows link I gave you? Windows includes the *Snipping Tool* which can do all this already. I do point out in my answer that a modern OS can already do all this. I just chose a tool that does a good job of making the task easier *for me*, but I could do the same with the default Mac tools.

Comment: So... free, easy to install, anyone can do it in one click tool (or, again... your OS).... or..... Stack needs to reinvent the wheel? Sounds like bad prioritization of devtime considering the ROI

Comment: @Martijn that  tools is very inconvenient (at least for me- it doesnt have event SELECT ALL and COPY). ok, I'll use 3rd party too, better, now i am convinced. thanks!

Comment: If Apple added the ability to draw freehand red circles when using Cmd+Shift+4+Space, I believe we could call macOS "feature-complete". @T.Todua I don't know why you are having such a hard time here. You don't need to use third-party tools at all. On Windows, Alt+PrintScreen works perfectly well; the result can be pasted in directly.

Comment: @CodyGray: see [Does the Preview app have a freehand pen/pencil tool?](//apple.stackexchange.com/q/173633); just open the image from the Desktop into Preview and draw.

Answer (score 1):

This has been implemented, so now you can paste or drag&drop images directly into the editor.

See: [Editor improvements for images and links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317576/191655).

[image: paste or drag and drop images into WYSIWYG editor]

Comment: thanks, would be excellect if quick crop will be also available, as screenshots often need to trim down to specific rectangle. just an idea.